# AngularJS: how to split up a long controller into modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, model

Building my first angular app and I don't understand how to split the code into smaller chunks. I just have one long run-on controller, but if I try to separate the code into separate sections (controllers, services, etc), suddenly the data isn't binding to the view anymore (ie. I update data, but changes aren't showing in the view/browser).

ie. I have a simple app that connects to an api to get a list of "Books", it then displays the list, and allows the user to navigate using pagination, or get more details for a single book, or update a book record (edit/delete).

I would like to split the functions up into separate controllers like:

- **search** controller: handles form validation, $http to api;
- **books** (list): displays results from search api;
- **book** (single) controller: each item in the books list is a single item with calls like "more details" and "edit/delete";
- **pagination** controller: functions to next/prev through books list;
- **messages** controller: display a success/error message when doing an action in a "search", "book", or "pagination" controllers.

Trouble is I don't know how to set this up, because if I use services to store/output the "books" model or "messages" model, when I make an update to this data through one of the controllers, the change doesn't automatically update the view (like it would if I updated a $scope variable that is linked to a controller).

From what I understand, a $scope variable in a view updates automatically because the `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` is binding to a region. But how would that work with a service? You don't use an `ng-service` tag, right...?

So let's say I have my searchController call the api, receive a json of all the books. I shove that into the booksService for storage. Then my booksController, which is responsible for updating the list view of all the books on the page, has to load this booksService to get the new data... but how does it know the data was updated? How do I link the data from the booksService, through the booksController, to display the new results in the view?

And also, how would I go about structuring the booksService -- how do I get searchController to pass in new data (to update a persistent variable I can use for the model), and then how do I get booksController to load in that new data? Do I need to create a call from within booksService to PUSH the new data to booksController, or should booksController have a call to PULL the new data from booksService (and if so, how would it know when it should make a PULL)?

As well, searchController and paginationController would be making a GET call with matching query to the same API (only difference would be the $page variable in the query). Should I be using a 'service' (or is it a factory?) to decouple that $http.get request?

Lastly, what's the best way to structure all of these controllers/services in a folder/file structure? Should I be aiming to separate each chunk onto a separate *.js file? Should I be using require.js to import the files? In this case, it's a single page of a website (where there could be additional other page like this one on the website). If I split the code into separate files, should I group the files in one folder per webpage basis? (ie. if I add a "users dashboard" page, all files would be stored in a separate folder from the "search books" page).

Sorry, I know I'm asking a lot, but this would really help me wrap my mind around the concepts involved in properly structuring an Angular app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all your controllers in this way in controller.js file.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope) {
    //do your search stuff
})
.controller('BookCtrl',function($scope){

})
.controller('PaginationCtrl',function($scope){

})
.controller('MessagesCtrl',function($scope){

});

//in your services.js file

angular.module('starter.services', [])

/**
 * A simple  service that returns some data.
 */

.factory('Search', function() {

  var somedata="from service";

  return {
    sample: function() {
         return somedata;
       }
    }
)};
```

you can invoke factory service from any controller like this

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, Search) {
//get data from factory service
    $scope.getdata=Search.sample();

})
```

also in your directive file

```
/*
its route map for the application 
all the page navigation are done here
common for the application 
*/
angular.module('app',[
'ui.router'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider',function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/',
            templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
            controller:'SearchCtrl'
        })
        .state('about',{
        url:'/about',
            templateUrl:'templates/about.html',
            controller:'aboutCtrl'      
        })

}])
```

In your home.html you can read the data by this way

```
<h2>{{$scope.getdata}}</h2>
```

Check out this link (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) and try the sample `tabs` app that simulate working of tab based apps .Ionicframework with angularjs is better for this type of apps.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! Does it matter in which order I load the JS files (ie. app before controller/services, or after...)? Do I have to invoke those modules as dependencies of `app` somehow? Also `var somedata="from service"` is supposed to go inside the function (I think you have a typo)?

Comment: You can keep the order like this app/controller/services.

Comment: Although the OP accepted this answer, it does not appear to address one of his main concerns – how does the  controller pass data to the service?

Comment: @Mawg, as of my understanding, a service will create an object when page load. So if you point a part of the scope to a part of the service $scope.A = Service.A They will essentially point to just one object and any modify in value of one will effect another. You can actually use this feature to share data from 1 service to multiple controller as long as the page not refresh. Note that if you point to new object, it will break the binding. It took me 2 days to realize what wrong with my array of object service so I also mention it here.

Comment: Factory is difference from Service in that factory create as an object when called. So each controller inject will be a new object.

This effect however only seen in Single page app (SPA) because there is no page reload, so if you not doing SPA, that different not worth consider. Document still prefer .factory over .service for service code though, maybe because it's less confusing and less prom to error from new user. Service is useful to sync a long form with many section that effect by previous input though since you can by pass lot of hassle from repeat calling API using same input.